# How do I change the text of a heading with a javascript button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button, text

noob here.
I want to make a variable out of some text, so that when I click it old text becomes new text.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1 id="id01">THis is the old text</h1>

<p>Click on "My Button" to display its value attribute.</p>

<button id="myBtn" name="myname" value="myvalue" 
onclick="alert(this.value)">My Button</button>

<p>Click on "Try it" to change the value attribute of "My Button".</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p><b>Tip:</b> Click on "My Button" before and after you have clicked on 
"Try it".</p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myBtn").value = "newButtonValue";
    document.getElementById("id01").value = "this is the new text";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

This is the first example I use, but var = would be a better alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use innerText not value.

```js
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myBtn").value = "newButtonValue";
    document.getElementById("id01").innerText = "this is the new text";
}
```

```html
<h1 id="id01">THis is the old text</h1>

<p>Click on "My Button" to display its value attribute.</p>

<button id="myBtn" name="myname" value="myvalue" 
onclick="alert(this.value)">My Button</button>

<p>Click on "Try it" to change the value attribute of "My Button".</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p><b>Tip:</b> Click on "My Button" before and after you have clicked on 
"Try it".</p>
```

Comment: This worked perfect! I want to be able to have different text, how do I make it so that .innertext = a var element?

Comment: Just replace "this is the new text" with the variable you want assigned to the text.